# Got `java.nio.BufferOverflowException` in pyspark dataframe count function

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark, pyspark, hadoop-yarn

I'm working with the following environment: `spark = 2.0.0`,`hdp = 2.5.3.0`,`python = 2.7`,`yarn-client`

My PySpark code works fine most of time.
However sometimes I get below exception on `df.count()` function

Code that works for me:

```
df= spark.read.orc("${path}")
df.count()
```

Code in which I get exception:

```
df= spark.read.orc("${path}")
df = df.cache()
df.count()
```

Stacktrace:

```
  Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 4.0 failed 4 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.3 in stage 4.0 (TID 9, apii): java.nio.BufferOverflowException +details
    Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 4.0 failed 4 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.3 in stage 4.0 (TID 9, apii): java.nio.BufferOverflowException
        at java.nio.Buffer.nextPutIndex(Buffer.java:521)
        at java.nio.HeapByteBuffer.put(HeapByteBuffer.java:169)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.columnar.BOOLEAN$.append(ColumnType.scala:286)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.columnar.compression.RunLengthEncoding$Encoder.compress(compressionSchemes.scala:143)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.columnar.compression.CompressibleColumnBuilder$class.build(CompressibleColumnBuilder.scala:103)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.columnar.NativeColumnBuilder.build(ColumnBuilder.scala:97)
```

Any help is appreciated :)

Comment: what is the size of the input data? how many executors do you have? have much RAM did you allocate for each executor?

Comment: Containers = 3 
cpu =3
memory =12288 MB 
Executors=2
data-size= 2GB

Comment: FYI My code is working fine for json data (2GB ) and when I run on ORC data (26 MB  copy of 2GB data) I get buffer overflow, Total record is 2M

Answer (score 1):

When using `cache()` on a RDD/dataframe, the memory allocated for `cached RDD` is taken from the executor memory.

i.e. if the executor memory was 8GB, and the size of the `cached RDD` is 3GB, the executor will have only 5GB of RAM (instead of 8GB) which might cause the `buffer overflow` issue you are facing.

I guess that increasing the RAM allocated for each executor and/or increasing the number of executors (usually together with increasing the number of partitions) might cause the `buffer overflow` error to disappear.

Short quote from **memory management** section in [spark-architecture](http://datastrophic.io/core-concepts-architecture-and-internals-of-apache-spark/) :

**Execution Memory**

- storage for data needed during tasks execution
- shuffle-related data

**Storage Memory**

- storage of cached RDDs and broadcast variables
- possible to borrow from execution memory (spill otherwise)
- safeguard value is 50% of Spark Memory when cached blocks are immune to eviction

Comment: Thanks for clean explanation. I just want to know what is the best way to set spark config dynamically based on data size. In my case datasize is not fixed its changing dynamically from 1GB to 100GB. My clusterconfig is (RAM=64GB, Node= Single node , Core=8)